# Is the combustion process in turbofans and turboshafts different?

Tags: turbofan, combustion, turboshaft

According to a journal paper, for a Gnome turboshaft engine, fuel-air equivalence ratio decreases as power output increases. However, for a CFM56 turbofan engine, the opposite trend is true, and equivalence ratio increases as engine thrust increases.

Why is there such a difference between these two types of turbine engines?

[image: Variations of equivalence ratio with power]

Comment: Can you please include (with links) both datasets?

Comment: Thank you. I have added an image of the data set in the question body above.

Comment: Please add the combustion chamber pressure at each data point. I suspect that you need a higher fuel-to-air ratio at low pressure to keep the combustion going, but without those pressure data this is just a guess. Also, besides the number of data points I fail to see the difference between turboshaft 1 and 2 - they have identical numbers.